# How to separate presentation and logic in Code Igniter helpers and views?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In a CodeIgniter application, I frequently dynamically generate HTML such as Bootstrap panels like this:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>{$content->heading}</div>
    <div class='panel-body'> 
        {$content->something}
        {$content->something_else}
        {$content->something_entirely_different}
    </div>
</div>
```

There is some logic involved as to how the content in `panel-body` is generated. I generally move logic like this to helper functions, which take an array of data from the database (i.e. data about documents) as input and return an array of formatted HTML panels like this that can be loaded into the final view.

I'm wondering if it's not better to move the static html out of here into a template file (i.e. `'/application/views/templates/panel_template.html'`) and generate the panel like this:

`$panel = $this->load->view('templates/panel_template', array('content'=>$content), TRUE); //third parameter forces the view to be interpreted as a string rather than print it to the browser`

...and load it later.

If anything, to me this certainly looks much cleaner and more according to MVC principles (where logic and views are not weaved together in the same files)
In short:

1. Is `$this->load->view();` heavy on a server? This boils down to: Is it worth it to load external files for (perceived) increased elegance/cleanliness rather than 'hardcode' bits of HTML in a PHP string?
2. Should I build HTML in helpers or use helpers to inject data into views, and load the results of those instead? If neither, then how?

Comment: The logic should stay in the controller, and I would encourage your thoughts of creating template views instead of passing data to a helper function containing html. I often load views in strings with no sign of extra server loads, but I have not benchmarked or tested eventual differences though.

Comment: @MichaelK Thanks. I am hesitant to include the building itself in the controller because this would bloat the controller file, which is why I prefer including it in a helper. How would you separate helper content and controller content?

Comment: I'm no MVC-expert, but I prefer to only put logic that has to do with the specific application in the controller. Views contain pure html, css, javascripts etc. I only use helpers to put more general and non-application-specific  functions, for instance calculations, general string manipulation and formatting etc., but I don't think it will hurt you to continue using helpers as holders of html. We all like different approaches for different reasons. I do not now if any approach are more server intense than the other, so I leave that up to others to answer.